# Are there new digital cameras that my old zoom lenses from my analog Yashica camera will fit?

Tags: lens-mount, yashica

I have an old analog camera (Yashica) with a bayonet lock and several zoom lenses for it. All of that was very high quality at the time and I would like to re-use it for a digital camera. Are any such digital cameras on the market?

Comment: beside the link in the accepted answer, check this: http://www.pebbleplace.com/Personal/Contax_db.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](http://galactinus.net/vilva/retro/eos_adapters.html) seems a good reference to use yashica/contaxt lens on Canon EOS D

But be aware that you will have to use manual mode.

Comment: Don't forget to manually stop down your aperture before taking the photograph either. On some lenses there's a difference between setting an aperture and actually stopping it down.

Comment: That link no longer works.

Comment: Link is still dead.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably find a basic CY adapter for any or the major 35mm or smaller mount types.

Fotodiox has a pretty good selection: [Contax/Yashica mount adapters](http://fotodioxpro.com/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=yashica)

Most adapters will only make the physical connection and leave you in complete manual mode.
Some of the nicer ones, like the [EOS adapter from fotodiox](http://fotodioxpro.com/index.php/contax-yashica-c-y-lens-to-canon-eos-with-dandelion-focus-confirmation-chip-fotodiox-pro-lens-mount-adapter.html) or those from ["HappyPageHK" on ebay](http://shop.ebay.com/happypagehk/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_from=&_ipg=&_trksid=p3686), also have focus confirmation chips that allow you to use some of the auto-focus features from newer cameras.

Comment: There's a pretty full selection of adapters here: http://fotodioxpro.com/index.php/lens-mount-adapters.html

Comment: Updated the answer a bit.